# What is the meaning of $n\in \aleph$

Tags: induction, cardinals

> Using mathematical induction, prove that, for each $n\in \aleph$
>
> $$n<3^n$$

Dear all, what is the meaning of "$n\in \aleph$" . How to substitute it and prove that? please give me one step or some basic information about that. what to do?

Comment: See [Alpeh number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number) in Wikipedia. But for $\aleph$ alone (no index), it's not very clear to me. Actually, since it's true for *any* cardinal, it may just mean "let $n$ be a cardinal". However it would be a particularly unwise notation (there is no set of all cardinal numbers).

Comment: "Mathematical induction" is usually followed by $\mathbb{N}$, and I think mathematical induction on cardinal numbers $\aleph_1, \cdots$ does not make sense. But I'm not very sure... (By the way, can mathematical induction be done on ordinal numbers $> \omega$?)

Comment: @JiminP Have a look at [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction). Just a creative use of the [axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) ;-)

Comment: If I don't misremember, $\aleph$ without subscript is often(?) used for $2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$, so the assertion is $\kappa < 3^\kappa$ for $\kappa < 2^{\aleph_0}$. But I may be misremembering.

Comment: @arbautjc Thank you! The definition is easier than I thought!

Comment: @arbautjc: Sure, but "_mathematical_ induction", with the qualifier, usually refers specifically to ordinary one-step-at-a-time induction over the naturals only.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm perfectly happy with this, it's the notation I found strange. Anyway, it does not differ much from [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).

Comment: @arbautjc: Yes, yes. (It may have been unclear, but I was responding to / expanding on your reply to JiminP).

Comment: Where did you see this question? It is possible that you confused $\Bbb N$ and $\aleph$. I saw many people whose $\aleph$ looks very much like $N$.

Comment: @arbautjc: transfinite induction has **nothing** to do with the axiom of choice. It's a construction of $\sf ZF$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure, but to provide a well-ordering, you will often need the axiom of choice. Admittedly, my previous sentence was not clear at all on this.

Answer (score 5):

Presumably it means $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$\aleph_0$ is the first infinite cardinal, it's the cardinality of the natural numbers. In the most common formalism of set theory, it's identified with $\omega$, the first infinite ordinal number, which in turn is identified with $\mathbb{N}$. So when you see $n \in \aleph_0$ what it means is $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm guessing that here $\aleph$ is written instead of $\aleph_0$. This is in line with the meaning of 'mathematical induction' (as opposed to other induction principles).

It seems to be an odd use of the notation, though.

In fact $\kappa < 3^{\kappa}$ is true for all cardinals $\kappa$, so it doesn't really matter what the author means by $\aleph$ if you want to prove this more general result.

Comment: Under the negation of the axiom of choice it is also true that $\kappa<3^\kappa$ for every cardinal $\kappa$ (even if, like me, you consider cardinal in the broader sense and not just the aleph numbers).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Oh yeah... I knew that, not sure why I said 'under AC'... maybe it had something to do with the question of whether or not $2^{\aleph_0}$ is an aleph. I've edited my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$n<3^{n}$
step 1. for $n=1$
$n<3^{n}$
step 2. $1<3^{1}$
$1<3$
It is the proof

Thanks for all.....Just I prove that. Please tell me I am correct or not? what are the missing steps? Sorry for my bad English....

Comment: You haven't done the induction step yet. You need to show that, assuming that $n<3^n$ is true, then $n+1<3^{n+1}$ is true.

Comment: why are you using "+1" to "n"?

Comment: If you're asking that question then you should (re-)read your notes on mathematical induction.

Comment: exactly it is the correct method. but my English knowledge is so bad. my all notes are withing the English........as well as it is also really hard to understand.please help me

Comment: What's your native language?

Comment: Sinhala from Srilanka. First time i doing maths and using International Language. So i am really aweary

Comment: See [here](http://si.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B6%9C%E0%B6%AB%E0%B7%92%E0%B6%AD_%E0%B6%85%E0%B6%B7%E0%B7%8A%E2%80%8D%E0%B6%BA%E0%B7%94%E0%B7%84%E0%B6%B1%E0%B6%BA). Unfortunately I don't have the time to teach you mathematical induction, and MSE isn't really the place for that anyway, but someone else might be able to help you (or you could try searching the internet for other sources).

Comment: Thanks My dear Friend Clive Newstead. Yes it is really helpful to me.Now i am following it.