# Notation question about defining a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If I'm given:

$\{ n^2 + n + 1 \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \subseteq \{ 2n + 1 \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$

Does this mean:

"The set $A$ where each element is made by putting a natural number in that formula (so for instance the first element of $A$ is $1^2 + 1 + 1 = 3$ and the second one is $2^2 + 2 + 1 = 7$ and so on...) and the set $B$ has each element to equal each natural number squared and added 1, and each element from $A$ is also found in $B$"

Is this the proper way to interpret it?

Comment: What do you mean by $n\in\aleph$? Do you mean $n\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: "The set of all numbers of the form $n^2+n+1$ for natural numbers $n$ is a subset of the set of all numbers of the form $2n+1$ for natural numbers $n$."  At least, assuming you meant $\Bbb N$ instead of $\aleph$...  In particular, this means that your characterization of $B$ is a bit off, since it contains all the natural numbers times $2$ and then plus $1$.

Comment: (I am more than certain, by the way, that I have seen this exact question before, including the mistake of $\Bbb N$ for $\aleph$.)

Comment: Ha! I knew that I wasn't imagining that. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616481/what-is-the-meaning-of-n-in-aleph (Well, not exact question, but close enough, considering my bad memory!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed, trusting that you intended for $\aleph$ to represent $\mathbb N$.

Just be careful with the wording: You want to say something like: "Every number of the form $n^2 + n + 1$, where $n \in \mathbb N$, can also be written in the form $2k+1$, where $k\in \mathbb N$." The $n$ used to make some element $x$ an element in the first set will usually not be the same $n$ which makes $x$ an element of the second set. To help make this distinction, we can call two possibly distinct natural numbers by using different variables, $n, k \in \mathbb N$.

So for example, when $n = 2$, then we know $7$ is in the first set, and it also is in the second set, since when $k = 3$, $\;2k+1 = 7$.

So your proof should start with: "Let $x \in \{n^2 + n + 1\mid n\in \mathbb N\}$. Then there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $x = n^2 + n + 1\ldots,\,$ and your aim is to arrive at the conclusion that there exists a $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $x = 2k+1$, for some $k\in \mathbb N$. Hence, $x \in \{2n+1\mid n\in \mathbb N\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are right if what you mean is $n \in \mathbb{N}$.